# Better jsonb schema for querying in postgres

Tags: postgresql, index, schema

I have a JSON with the following structure:

```
uid | item
1   |[{"id":1, "m":"123", "s":1},{"id":2, "msg":"on","s":2},{"id":3, "msg":"of","s":1}]
2   |[{"id":1, "m":"yes", "s":2},{"id":3, "msg":"gh","s":0}]
3   |[{"id":1, "m":"qa", "s":1},{"id":4, "msg":"ks"},{"id":5, "m":"test"}]
```

I want to query this table based on `id` and get rows based on matched object values. For e.g. for `id=3` I want:

```
uid | id | m  | s
 1  | 3  | of | 1
 2  | 3  | gh | 0
```

This table has over 500M rows so I would need an index. Using `GIN(item jsonb_path_ops)` with `item @> '[{"id": 3}]'` works, but I don't know how to get the exact json object from array that matched.

I can turn the JSON structure to:

```
{
    "1": { "m":"123", "s": 1 },
    "2": { "m":"on", "s":2 },
    "3": { "m":"of", "s": 1 }
}
```

and use `GIN(item)` and check for key exists with `?` and then try to fetch the key value. But the index size might increase which might be an overkill given that I only want to search based on id.

Maybe I can use a B-Tree index but not sure how. What should be my JSON structure for most efficient querying? and what index should be used so that I get only the matched object from the array?

Some facts:

1. Cardinality of `id` <<< `uid`. (id = ~100,000, uid = ~500,000,000)
2. Normalizing this turns this table to 500M*10,000 rows which is extremely slow.
3. Each JSON array will have upto 50 objects only.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 questions here;

---

First one is the index structure.

- You can use gin(item) here (without jsonb_path_ops). It will be just fine. You are querying  for key (id) only not the full path.
- You can create an expression index (or an gin index on a generated column) for extracting id field values to an integer[] value. Most probably this index will be smaller than jsonb index (~%10 smaller). But I am not sure whether it's faster for your case.

Here is an example for second usage.

Create an immutable function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION to_my_int_array (jsonb) RETURNS integer[] AS 
$$
  SELECT
      ARRAY(
        SELECT (jsonb_array_elements($1) ->> 'id')::integer
      );

$$
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

Create an expression index with the function above:

```
CREATE INDEX ON my_table USING gin (to_my_int_array (item));
```

Filter the query with function;

```
SELECT
    mt.uid,
    my_item.*
  FROM my_table mt,
  LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(mt.item) ae,
  LATERAL jsonb_to_record(ae) AS my_item (id int, m text, s int)
  WHERE
    to_my_int_array(mt.item) @> '{1}'::integer[];
```

---

Second question is the output. The query above also shows output for version 11. After version 12, you can simply use the query below;

```
SELECT
    uid,
    my_item.*
  FROM my_table mt,
  LATERAL jsonb_to_record(jsonb_path_query_first(mt.item, '$[*] ? (@.id == 1) ')) 
    AS my_item(id int, m text, s int)
  WHERE
    mt.item @> '[{"id": 1}]';

| uid | id  | m   | s   |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 1   | 123 | 1   |
| 2   | 1   | yes | 2   |
| 3   | 1   | qa  | 1   |
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm using PG 11. I already have something similar for the second part. It's the first part I'm worried about. Could you please point me to a resource that does something like your 2nd bullet point of first answer. That looks like a good strategy.

Comment: I could extract a postgres array for `id` but I don't want to add this column physically to my table because it's size is too big. Is it possible to use this array directly in a GIN index? I tried but didn't succeed. I used `SELECT ARRAY(select jsonb_extract_path_text(jsonb_array_elements(p.item), '1')) from test p`

Comment: To test the index performance only, I just selected * without any lateral joins. I've only tried on 1M entries but gin creation on the generated array(`a`) took 80 secs and plain gin(`b`) took 38 sec and with jsonb_path_ops(`c`) took 21 sec. Search results were best for `a`=300ms, `b`=3.1s, `c`=3.9s. `b`'s size was almost 2 times than the other 2. Now my only problem is, this table gets lots of inserts, which might become slow with `a`. I gained a little time by switching to 2nd JSON in OP structure and using `jsonb_object_keys`. It returns a set and I wrote a fn to convert it to the array.